# Show that $\rho:G\to GL_3(\Bbb{C})$ is irreducible if and only if there is no common eigenvector for the matrices $\rho_g$ with $g \in G$.

Tags: group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-groups, representation-theory

> Let $\rho\colon G\longrightarrow GL_{3}(\mathbb{C})$ be a representation of a finite group. Show that $\rho$ is irreducible if and only if there is no common eigenvector for the matrices $\rho_{g}$ with $g \in G$.

My question is how can I do the demostration and what if I aplied this to dim $2$, I'm starting to study the subject of representation of groups and I'm using the book by Benjamin Steinberg: *Representation Theory of Finite Groups.*

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Follow-up exercise: show that this is false in general, when $G$ is not assumed finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $v$ is a common eigenvector for the matrices $\rho_g$ ($g\in G$), then clearly $\mathbb C v$ is an invariant subspace of $\mathbb C^3$ and therefore $\rho$ is not irreducible.

On the other hand, if $\rho$ is not irreducible, you can write $\mathbb C^3$ as the direct $V\oplus W$ where $V$ and $W$ are non-trivial subspaces of $\mathbb C^3$ and $V$ and $W$ are stable with respect to the action $\rho$. But, since $\dim\mathbb C^3=3$, one of the spaces $V$ and $W$ must be $1$-dimensional. Assume that it is $V$. Then $V=\mathbb C v$ for some non-null vector $v$, which will be then a common eigenvector for the matrices $\rho_g$.

Now, do you think that this argument also works in $\mathbb C^2$ instead of $\mathbb C^3$?

Comment: Yeah, this argument works, but I am confused in the dimension of the space, I thought it was 3, but a friend told me that when u work on the real field the dimension of C^3 is 4, that is correct?

Comment: If you see $\mathbb C^3$ as a complex vector space, then its dimension is $3$. But if you see it as a real vector space, then its dimension is $6$. But it will **not** be $4$.

Comment: I see, thanks for that.