# How does the order of the group (finite or infinite) matter for the reducibility criterion for representations of degree $3$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

It is easy to show and a well-known trick, that

if $\varphi: G \to GL(V)$ is a complex representation of a group $G$ with $\dim(V)=2$, then $\varphi$ is irreducible if and only if there exists no (non-zero) vector $v\in V$ that is an eigenvector of $\varphi_{g}$ for all $g\in G$.

This is simply a consequence of the fact that a non-trivial (and "real") potentially invariant subspace of $V$ has to have dimension $1$.

Now apparently this argument easily carries over to $3$ dimensional representations, since also here exactly one such subspace needs to be of dimension $1$. This extension of the above argument was mentioned in my textbook (Steinberg) but with the restriction that in contrast to the $2$ dimensional case this only works for [finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538164/show-that-rhog-to-gl-3-bbbc-is-irreducible-if-and-only-if-there-is-no-co), i.e. groups of order $|G|=n<\infty$.

However, I cannot see why the argument holds only for finite groups? Grateful for any hints.

(I suspect that it might be connected somehow with the problem that one only can check the eigenvector criterion for finite instances, but I cannot see why one wouldn't be able to use induction, for example).

Comment: A different way this fails is if you keep the group finite, but change the field. For example, consider the group $G$ of order 2 acting on $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ by swapping $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$. Clearly the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $(1, 1)$ is fixed under the action of $G$, but it has no complementary one-dimensional subspace which is also fixed by $G$. So one really needs semisimplicity to make this argument (which for finite groups you get in characteristic zero, or characteristic not dividing $|G|$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $G$ of all nonsingular complex $3 \times 3$ matrices $A = (\alpha_{ij})$ with $\alpha_{12} = \alpha_{13}=0$ is reducible (it has a $2$-dimensional $G$-invariant subspace spanned by the second and third basis vectors), but there is no common eigenvector.

When the group is finite, we can apply Maschke's Theorem to get a $G$-invariant complement of any such subspace, but that result is not true in general for infinite groups.

Comment: Is the representation is given by the action of G on $\mathbb{C}^3$?

Comment: Yes that's right!